# SSRS: How to create 'Color Analytics Map' in Reporting Services 2008 / Report Builder 3.0

Tags: dictionary, reporting-services, report, reportbuilder, reporting-services-map

I'm setting up a map report in Reporting Services (Report Builder 3.0) running on a SQL Server 2008 RC2.

I've got a dataset like this:

```
CODE   VAL
AF  11
AL  7
DZ  7
VI  15
AD  7
AO  6
AI  8
AQ  10
```

I've downloaded the shape (.shp) file from here: http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/. I imported this file to my report and in the dialog 'Select fields to match spatial data and analytical data' I've registered a match between the spatial data field 'ISO_A2' and my own 'CODE' field. I've checked manually that these columns match.

I've set my VAL-field as the field to 'visualize' in the Wizard.

I've changed the distribution-range in the 'Map Color Rules Properties' dialog as starting from 1 through 20.

When I preview my report, all the countries are rendered with **No Color** (all backgroundss are grey as the background)! I tried a lot of difference color setups but no luck. Seems like the spatial data and my test dataset doesn't get join correctly!? :(

How can I ensure that the spatial data and my analytical data are joined correctly?

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Any solutions/hints highly appreciated! ;)

Regards
Alex